# Remove HTTPS from Devise confirmation link when using Rack::SSLEnforcer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, devise

I'm using Devise and Rack::SSLEnforcer in a Rails app. When users receive their confirmation email, it looks something like:

http://mysite.com:443/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=123456789xxx

The link is auto-generated by Devise's confirmation_url method.

This link shouldn't have the port 443 attached to it. In theory, I don't need the link to be to the https address, but it's fine if it is. At minimum, it should be https at the front, not port 443 at the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: protocol in URL should be `https://` if it is really SSL.

Comment: The URL is auto-generated--I should have specified that--I've updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing the Devise views and customizing the link being generated. You can install the Devise views with this command:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Make sure to read the Devise documentation because you may need to customize some other stuff when you do this (depending on your particular situation).

With that complete, you can now edit the file at

```
app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
```

To make the link always generate as SSL, just customize the `link_to` call:

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token, :protocol => "https") %>
```

Comment: This seemed to work. In theory, it'd be nice to have a way of disabling that appended 443 in a global way, but this solved the problem for me. Thanks!