# Devise redirects to https instead of http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm facing an issue and after some searches I couldn't find a solution. It's the first time I deploy an app using Devise and the behavior for the login/logout & registration is kinda strange. In fact when I'm trying to do one of these 3 actions, the browser redirect me to the desired page but with HTTPS instead of HTTP.

In my production.rb I added this line :

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'sd.foo.bar' }
```

I checked in config files and I couldn't figure why http is active for that 3 cases because in other page, the navigation works as expected with HTTP. I don't really know if I made a mistake or something like that but any help would be appreciate here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably it's not a bug but a feature. Why do you want to disable HTTPS for your login/registration?

Comment: Well because it's a small application maximum 3 or 4 different user and data is not *security national dependant*. I don't have a SSL certificate and I don't really want to spent many time to configure it since I don't need it here.

Comment: Are you using the confirmable module of devise ?

Comment: You definitely don't need national-security data to justify the use of an SSL certificate, imo all Web apps should force HTTPS. To your question: do you mean that when you visit an HTTP URL you are automatically redirected to HTTPS? Or that the generated links point to HTTPS? If you refer to the latter you can pass :protocol => "http" to the link helpers and see what happens

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038632/remove-https-from-devise-confirmation-link-when-using-racksslenforcer

Comment: I'm redirected to a https address but the link is pointing to a http address. I have already checked the link you gave me before but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found a solution. I know this is know known as a best practice and I should stop doing that but in my precise case, It's juste a very small application for me and 2/3 friends so I don't really need SSL. I just add a rule in nginx to redirect ssl requests to the port 80 and it solved everything.

Comment: You can run small applications on Heroku for free including SSL.

Comment: @Hito, Even I've got the same situation. Could you tell, how you did the redirection part?